# Processing of two dimension list in scala

Tags: scala

I want process to two dimension list in scala: eg:

Input:

```
List(
  List(‘John’, ‘Will’, ’Steven’),
  List(25,28,34),
  List(‘M’,’M’,’M’)
)
```

O/P:

```
John|25|M
Will|28|M
Steven|34|M
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Ankit, can you edit your post to add a precise question and the code you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like `transpose`?

Comment: I got the expected using for loop, I have posted the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with indexes, and while working with indexes `List` is not probably the wisest choice, and also your input is not a well-structured two dimensional list, I would suggest you to have a dedicated data structure for this:

```scala
// you can name this better
case class Input(names: Array[String], ages: Array[Int], genders: Array[Char])
val input = Input(Array("John", "Will", "Steven"), Array(25, 28, 34), Array('M', 'M', 'M'))
```

By essence, this question is meant to use indexes with, so this would be a solution using indexes:

```scala
input.names.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (name, index) => 
      (name, inp.ages(index), inp.genders(index))
  } 
// or use a for instead
```

But always try to keep an eye on `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while working with array indexes. A safer and more "Scala-ish" approach would be zipping, which also take care of arrays with non-equal sizes:

```scala
input.names zip inp.ages zip inp.genders map { // flattening tuples
  case ((name, age), gender) => (name, age, gender)
}
```

But this is a little bit slower (one iteration per zipping, and an iteration in mapping stage, I don't know if there's an optimization for this).
And in case you didn't want to go on with this kind of modeling, the algorithm would stay just the same, except for explicit unsafe conversions you will need to do from `Any` to `String` and `Int` and `Char`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected o/p from for loop

```
for(i<-0 to 2)
{
 println()
   for(j<-0 to 2)
      {
         print(twodlist(j)(i)+"|")
      }
}
```

Note: In loop we can use list length instead of 2 to make it more generic.